# Why link become active without adding the class name

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 9 for the project. I'm having problem on active menu on current page. Menu become active only when I added the route to href. Active class added automatically on list class.

When I added

```
{{ route('any-route-name') }}
```

to my link as below sample

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('any-route-name') }}"> <i class="fa fa-building nav-icon"></i> Companies</a>
</li>
```

an active class added to list. Did an inspect element, active class added to the list as below sample

```
<li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('any-route-name') }}"> <i class="fa fa-building nav-icon"></i> Companies</a>
</li>
```

did inspection on view page source but active class not exist. The moment I remove the

```
{{ route('any-route-name') }}
```

active class no more added. Can any one explain/assist me on this. I don't have any JS to add active class after page rendered.

Answer (score 0):

is('admin/cities')) ? 'active' : '' }}"> 
**Approach 2. Starting with the URL**
is('admin/cities*')) ? 'active' : '' }}">

Comment: Please explain the problem and your solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link @if(Request::segment(1) == 'any-route-name') active @endif" href="{{ route('any-route-name') }}"> <i class="fa fa-building nav-icon"></i> Companies</a>
</li>
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Actually the active class not on a tag, it's on li tag. Beside that, doing segment checking or current route name checking are not the problems. The problems on using the {{ route('any-route-name') }}, without even adding the request segment, by just calling {{ route('any-route-name') }}, active class added. Any how I will try now, and revert back result.

Comment: It's doesn't work. `<li class="nav-item @if(Request::segment(1) == 'user*') active @endif">
            <a class="nav-link" href=" {{ route('users') }} ">
                <i class="fa fa-user-md nav-icon"></i> User Management</a>
        </li>` when I call route name user.create the active class not applied as well. Calling route users, its works. If I remove request segment checking, than call to route users, active menu works. I do not know how the active class added, w/o me adding it via the segment checking.

Comment: If I do only `<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href=" {{ route('users') }} "><i class="fa fa-user-md nav-icon"></i> User Management</a>`, and click the link, some how the menu become active, and active class added. Checking on view page source active class not present. Inspect element active class present.